# How to scroll through a div by dragging and not by using the scroll bars

Tags: javascript, scroll, draggable

I am working on a project that uses a touch-screen interface.  I have a div inside of a smaller div, so the smaller div has scroll bars to access the rest of the first div. Here is the basic code for it.

```
.div1{
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
}
.div2{
      height: 50px;
      width: 50px;
}
```

and the html is:

```
<div id = "div2" class="div2">
 <div id="div1" class="div1"></div>
</div>
```

Using javascript, I would like to be able to scroll through div2 by pressing (since it is a touch screen) an unoccupied part of the screen and dragging along the div.  Basically, the scroll feature would behave the way google maps does when you click and drag in it. Can anybody help me with this? Thanks in advance!

### Note

In terms of mouse actions, pressing is equivalent to clicking here, just to be clear.  I am also working in Firefox only, so cross-browser compatibility is not an issue.

Comment: You're missing a 2nd `</div>` in your HTML.

Comment: you also need `overflow:scroll;` in the div2 css :P

Comment: The scroll bars show up without that so it actually doesn't need it. Thanks anyway though.

Comment: ah... must be chrome then.  it just overflows and doesn't show scroll bars

Comment: Got ya. I'm working in firefox only. I'll add that to the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This works...I'd started making it for mobile safari before you cited FireFox...so it may have a little extra...

```js
var _startX = 0;
var _startY = 0;
var _offsetX = 0;   
var _offsetY = 0;
var _dragElement;
document.onmousedown = OnMouseDown;
document.onmouseup = OnMouseUp;

function OnMouseDown(event){
  document.onmousemove = OnMouseMove;
    _startX = event.clientX;
  _startY = event.clientY;
  _offsetX = document.getElementById('div1').offsetLeft;
  _offsetY = document.getElementById('div1').offsetTop;
  _dragElement = document.getElementById('div1');

}

function OnMouseMove(event){
    _dragElement.style.left = (_offsetX + event.clientX - _startX) + 'px';
  _dragElement.style.top = (_offsetY + event.clientY - _startY) + 'px';
}

function OnMouseUp(event){
  document.onmousemove = null;
  _dragElement=null;
}
```

```css
.div1{position:absolute; height:500px; width: 500px; z-index:1; background-color:red;}
.div2{position:absolute; top:100px; left:100px; height:100px; width:100px; z-index:2; overflow:hidden; display:block;}
```

```html
<div class="div2" id="div2">
  <div class="div1" id="div1">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you may want to add some qualifiers so that it can't be scrolled out of view

Comment: Nice. Did you get this from a tutorial online by chance? I have almost the exact same code for buttons i'm placing in the div but I wasn't sure it would work for a div. Also, if I was calling this from my javascript and didn't want to place the JS in my html, would `document.getElementById("div1")` be the same as just using document? Thanks for the response!

Comment: at some point yes, but for this I was just pulling back out of my projects...I think some of it was from developer.apple.com. I just googled `_dragElement` and found this one which seems to be very similar, so I'm sure I read this, or someone elses port of it (if this isn't copying someone else itself :) ): http://luke.breuer.com/tutorial/javascript-drag-and-drop-tutorial.aspx (I don't typically use the underscore when choosing variable names)

Comment: you can still use `document.getElementById` when using a separate JS file

Answer (score 0):

I found this nice JQuery plugin (Not sure if you are ok with using JQuery or not)

http://digitalillusion.altervista.org/wordpress/pages/dragscroller/viewport-test.html

Comment: JQuery isn't an option. Thanks for the response though.