# Angularjs: how to scroll through a div and load more data like Google Map? (no scrollbar)

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, plugins, scroll

My question is same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914360/how-to-scroll-through-a-div-by-dragging-and-not-by-using-the-scroll-bars) but I am looking for a solution in Angularjs. 
I have a list like this in my screen:

```
1
2
3
0
6
8
```

The action for user is like google map that you can drag... but in this case only up and down.
When it reaches to up or down more data needs to be loaded

```
 <div style="overflow:hidden">
     <div data-ng-repeat="item in events">
     ...
```

Can you please tell me what can be the best approach? and if there is any plugin for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, what about this:

```
var containerHeight = 200;
var loadMargin = 10;

var i;

angular.module('Scroll', []).controller('ScrollCtrl', function($scope) {
    $("#content").draggable({
        axis: 'y',
        drag: function(evt, ui) {
            var minTop = containerHeight - $("#content").height();

            if (ui.position.top < minTop + loadMargin) {                
                //Load some more stuff here... $http anyone?
                $scope.list.push(i);
                i += 1;
                console.log('Loading!!!');

                //If you load ur stuff with $http or an Angular service
                //in principle you wont need this $digest
                $scope.$digest();
            }            
        }
    });

    $scope.list = [];
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i ++) {
        $scope.list.push(i);
    }
});
```

Ok we need to set the height of the container, so it knows when to start loading, and loadMargin is basically how much you need to scroll it for it to start loading. If it's set to zero it means it will only start loading after you reach the bottom, so it's nice to have it set to some non-zero value so it starts loading before.

Here you have a fiddle to see it in action:
https://jsfiddle.net/thepeak/4to69oxo/

Comment: For me it's saying draggable is not a function!

Comment: That's from jQuery UI, make sure you've added that lib to your page :)

Comment: Is there pure angular solution to this? I found angular-UI not sure if it support draggable should try

Comment: Well, lets see, if you can't use jQueryUI for some reason, this can be implemented with a couple Javascript functions, yes... jQueryUI is here: https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js
I prefer to do it with jQueryUI because its prettier and easier, but if you have a good reason not to use it, well... yeah it's possible

Comment: I see. I read this " AngularJS doesn't play well with widgets that modify the DOM which includes much of jQuery UI" and because of that I was thinking about alternative...

Comment: Don't panic, that's true, but it's about widgets and playing with DOM, we're not using widgets, or modifying DOM in any way, we're just modifying an attribute (the element position), it's gonna be fine :)

Answer (score -1):

[ngInfiniteScroll](http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/demo_basic.html) is a custom Angular directive that works well.

**Update:**
The link above is now dead, it seems it have been moved to https://sroze.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/

Comment: thanks but that doesn't work with dragging it only works with arrows