# How to click and drag a large view like in google maps?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Suppose I have a large view with scroll in both x and y direction and instead of scrolling with mouse scroll, I need to drag and move to navigate through the entire view like in google maps

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="dragable_content">
    <img src="https://geology.com/world/world-map.gif" style="height:100rem;"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

how do I achieve this? preferably using only pure js

Comment: Maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914360/how-to-scroll-through-a-div-by-dragging-and-not-by-using-the-scroll-bars

Comment: Alternatively use an [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) tag (example of this, see link). This will only work with external resources if the server allows it.

Comment: @PeterKrebs I'm not trying to create a google type map, I'm only looking for it's drag and scroll functionality

Comment: An iframe displays whatever is in it in a scrollable view, can be any website (or just a HTML page with the full-screen image in it. Just using your image's src might work too). Doesn't have to be a map, it just happened to be the example from the official documentation. Just try it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the solution provided by @grisuu in the comments

I was able to whip up this:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vzc9brka/3/)

```js
var _startX = 0;
var _startY = 0;
var _offsetX = 0;           
var _offsetY = 0;
var _dragElement;
document.onmousedown = OnMouseDown;
document.onmouseup = OnMouseUp;

function OnMouseDown(event){
  document.onmousemove = OnMouseMove;
    _startX = event.clientX;
  _startY = event.clientY;
  _offsetX = document.getElementById('div1').offsetLeft;
  _offsetY = document.getElementById('div1').offsetTop;
  _dragElement = document.getElementById('div1');

}

function OnMouseMove(event){
    _dragElement.style.left = (_offsetX + event.clientX - _startX) + 'px';
  _dragElement.style.top = (_offsetY + event.clientY - _startY) + 'px';
}

function OnMouseUp(event){
  document.onmousemove = null;
  _dragElement=null;
}
```

```css
html{ 
  background-color:green;
  overflow: hidden;
}


.div1{position:absolute; height:500px; width: 500px; z-index:1;}
```

```html
<div class="div1" id="div1">

    <div style="height:50px;width:50px;background-color:red;"></div>
    <div style="position:absolute;top:75px;left:100px;height:50px;width:50px;background-color:blue;"></div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I implemanted the same feature for my personal project by editing arsher's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72257677/10491674) and I want to share the code I ended up with here.

Here are some notes:

- This code does not use css at all, it's using `scrollTo` instead.
- I'm using `draggable='false'` on the image to prevent browser dragging feature on images.
- `document.documentElement.scrollTop / .scrollLeft` could have some browser support issues, there are many ways to get document scroll position value, many of them didn't work for me and this one did

```js
/* check browser support, tested on Chrome v108
**********************************************************************/

let _startX = 0,
    _startY = 0,
    _scrollTop = 0,
    _scrollLeft = 0;

document.onmousedown = OnMouseDown;
document.onmouseup = OnMouseUp;

function OnMouseDown(event) {
    document.onmousemove = OnMouseMove;
    _startX = event.clientX;
    _startY = event.clientY;
    _scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    _scrollLeft = document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
}

function OnMouseMove(event) {
    window.scrollTo({
        left: _scrollLeft + (_startX - event.clientX),
        top: _scrollTop + (_startY - event.clientY)
    });
}

function OnMouseUp() {
    document.onmousemove = null;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="dragable_content">
    <img draggable='false' src="https://geology.com/world/world-map.gif" style="height:100rem;" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Additional point: In this approach your movement is limited to the image size, _you do not get infinite scroll_, that was a deal breaker for me