# Moving svg div inside another div with mousemove

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Hello I will need to know if there is a way to move a svg div inside another div with mousemove, I only find tutorials with background-image I tried some examples to fit it with a div but it doesn’t work.

My main div is 500px x 500px and my svg card, my map is 3000px x 3000px and it is therefore my second div that I want to move to see the rest of the map while remaining in my main div.

HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <svg
        width="3000"
        height="3000"
        viewBox="0 0 793.74998 793.75"
        version="1.1"
        id="svg5"
        inkscape:export-filename="bg.svg"
        inkscape:export-xdpi="25.4"
        inkscape:export-ydpi="25.4"
        xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
        xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <sodipodi:namedview
            id="namedview7"
            pagecolor="#ffffff"
            bordercolor="#000000"
            borderopacity="0.25"
            inkscape:showpageshadow="2"
            inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
            inkscape:pagecheckerboard="0"
            inkscape:deskcolor="#d1d1d1"
            inkscape:document-units="px"
            showgrid="false" />
        <defs
            id="defs2" />
        <g
            inkscape:label="Calque 1"
            inkscape:groupmode="layer"
            id="layer1">
            <ellipse
            style="fill:#0000ff;stroke-width:1.32292;stroke-miterlimit:3.4"
            id="path1514"
            cx="140.29713"
            cy="162.9257"
            rx="63.360001"
            ry="76.937141" />
            <ellipse
            style="fill:#0000ff;stroke-width:1.32292;stroke-miterlimit:3.4"
            id="path1516"
            cx="235.33713"
            cy="554.40002"
            rx="90.514282"
            ry="92.777145" />
            <ellipse
            style="fill:#0000ff;stroke-width:1.32292;stroke-miterlimit:3.4"
            id="path1518"
            cx="546.47998"
            cy="255.70285"
            rx="93.908569"
            ry="117.66856" />
            <ellipse
            style="fill:#0000ff;stroke-width:1.32292;stroke-miterlimit:3.4"
            id="path1520"
            cx="611.84644"
            cy="647.17712"
            rx="123.06929"
            ry="90.514282" />
        </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS File:

```
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: beige;
}

.container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 5px solid #000000;
    overflow: hidden;
}

svg {
    --x: 0px;
    --y: 0px;
    position: relative;
    top: var(--x);
    right: var(--y);
}
```

JS File:

```
const el = document.querySelector("svg");

el.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  el.style.setProperty('--x', -e.offsetX + "px");
  el.style.setProperty('--y', -e.offsetY + "px");
});
```

Thank's for help !!

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914360/how-to-scroll-through-a-div-by-dragging-and-not-by-using-the-scroll-bars#6915243